# laravel class not found - Class 'GoogleMaps' not found

Tags: laravel, google-maps, laravel-5.4

I am using https://github.com/alexpechkarev/google-maps package with laravel 5.4 to create a google map and get driving distance from one point to another,
But When i call this function,

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError
(E_ERROR)    Class 'GoogleMaps' not found
```

d

```
$d['a'] = \GoogleMaps::load('geocoding')
        ->setParamByKey('place_id', 'ChIJd8BlQ2BZwokRAFUEcm_qrcA')
        ->get();
```

I have installed the package via

```
composer require alexpechkarev/google-maps:1.0.8
```

and added aliases,'providers' in config/app.php

```
'providers' => [
    ...
    'GoogleMaps\ServiceProvider\GoogleMapsServiceProvider',
]

'aliases' => [
    ...
    'GoogleMaps' => 'GoogleMaps\Facade\GoogleMapsFacade',
]
```

why am i getting this error,Cannot find a way around it,Does anybody have an answer

Comment: did you run composer dumpautoload

Comment: @lewis4u yes i did,But same error.

Comment: is your config cached?

Comment: @lagbox ,yes config is cached..i have moved to ivory google maps,and it works.dont know what is wrong with Alex's pkg,maybe something i missed.

Answer (score 0):

You are registering the providers and alias wrong. Try this in config/app.php

```
'providers' => [
    GoogleMaps\ServiceProvider\GoogleMapsServiceProvider::class,
]

'aliases' => [
    'GoogleMaps' => GoogleMaps\Facade\GoogleMapsFacade::class,
]
```